# How to use browser's default basic auth dialog pop up in angular2

Tags: angular, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

[image: Error image]

I get the above error(401 unauthorised) on making a http post request to a server. I find many online sources suggesting to intercept it and make my own login interface but I would like to use the browser's default login interface for basic auth.

[image: Browser's basic login interface]

How could one pop up the browser's default basic auth dialog on receiving 401 unauthorised status in angular2 instead of just logging it as an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solved : Angular 4.3 HTTPClient Basic Authorization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894628/solved-angular-4-3-httpclient-basic-authorization-not-working)

Comment: have the same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: Is there any solution around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same Issue here. Working chrome with :

```
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.withCredentials = true;
          xhttp.open("GET", "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd", true);
          xhttp.send();
```

Use "user" and "passwd" as credentials for this endpoint. Don't know your code but exceptions shows XMLHttpRequest. therefore withCredentials should do the job