# Angular 4.3 HTTPClient Basic Authorization not working

Tags: java, spring, angular, google-chrome, tomcat

I am trying to implement basic authorization in `Angular 4` using the newly released `HttpClient`.

I am trying to connect to a `Spring` application running on `Tomcat` with exposed `REST` APIs.

I have the following code in my `LoginComponent`:

```
onSubmit(user){
   console.log(user);
   const body = JSON.stringify({username: user.userName, password: user.password});

   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
   headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

   this.http.post('my url here',body, {headers: headers}).subscribe(response => {
         console.log(response);
   }, err => {
      console.log("User authentication failed!");
   });
}
```

However, the request does not add `Authorization` header at all.

This is from the `Chrome` tools `Network` tab:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?
How can I make this work ?

---

Update 1: Its still not working:

I changed my two lines as below:

```
headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I am getting header in the request as expected. This is from `Chrome`:

[image]

However, the post call is still failing.

At server side, my code is:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String authCredentials = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if(authCredentials == null) {
        logger.info("Request with no basic auth credentials {}", request.getRequestURL());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
    }

    // do my stuff
}
```

Call is never reaching `do my stuff`. `authCredentials` is `null`.

This is from `chrome`:

[image]

How to proceed ?

Comment: from which package did you imported `http` - `@angular/common/http` or `@angular/http`

Comment: @AjitSoman: @angular/common/http...

Comment: Did Ben's answer work for you ? Did you get any error in console regarding cors?

Comment: I installed a CORS plugin in google chrome to work my way around the CORS issues for debugging and running in development mode.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`HttpHeaders` is immutable, so you need to assign the result of the function to override the `headers` object each call.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Source: [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)

Comment: "assign the result of the function to override the headers object each call". Can you please elaborate on this ?

Comment: Look at the code, instead of simply `headers.append()`, you have to do `headers = headers.append()`, as `headers.append()` creates a new headers object, which you were previously not using

Comment: Oh! sorry! noticed now.. I thought you just pasted my two lines!! will try it.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi can your backend cors configuration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
         UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
     }
 }
```

Your angular request should be like that,

```
import { Http , Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

You can also check githup repo sample demo
[spring mvc with angular2/4](https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac/tree/master/src/main/webapp/app)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and authorization header was not going with post request.
This was my authenticate function

```
authenticate(username, password) {
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });

return this.httpClient.post<any>('<your-login-url>',{headers}).pipe(
 map(
   userData => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('username',username);
    return userData;
   }
 )
);
```

I did not know that post requires second argument as body and third as headers.
After coming this question I found it from question itself that I need to send a second argument as blank json because I dont have anything in body.

And here is the correct code for above authenticate function

```
authenticate(username, password) {
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) });

return this.httpClient.post<any>('<your-login-url>',{},{headers}).pipe(
 map(
   userData => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('username',username);
    return userData;
   }
 )
);
```

Which is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RequestOptions` to set headers to your post request.

```
    import { Http,Headers,RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    ..
    ..
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this.http.post('my url here',body, options).subscribe(response => {
             console.log(response);
       }, err => {
          console.log("User authentication failed!");
       });
```

Comment: Thanks.. but am trying to use the new release HttpClient (Angular 4.3)..

Comment: RequestOptions is not working with HttpHeaders from @angular/common/http

Comment: RequestOption work only with `http` of old package `@anguar/http` .

Comment: Did you have spring security in your project ? . also did you configured cors filter in your backend